# Saving an array for future use in a chrome extension (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a website blocker in JavaScript that can be installed as a Chrome extension. I am trying to find a way to save the *blockedSites* array in a text file or whatever would be the most convenient so that it would maintain its current state when Chrome restarts. How would I do this? I have been trying things for a long time, and I don't know what the best option would be, or how to do it.

```
// array containing the list of blocked sites
const blockedSites = ["youtube.com", "twitter.com"];


// check array for the current URL, replace old HTML to the above code if a match is found
if (blockedSites.toString().includes(window.location.hostname)) {
    document.body.innerHTML = genHTML();
    console.log("true")
};
```

Comment: Please see this. [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using chrome's extension storage
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/

Comment: How can I do this? I'm not sure how to implement it

Comment: As mentioned in the link you'll need to add
` "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
`
to the manifest file, then in the code
`
chrome.storage.sync.set({ blockedSites: JSON.stringify(blockedSites)});
`
to write and
`
chrome.storage.sync.get(["blockedSites"]).then((result) => {
 blockedSites = result.blockedSites;
});
`
to read.
Having trouble with the formatting but I think you'll get it